# How to make a custom keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode, special-characters

Can I create a new keyboard layout or add Unicode characters to my current keyboard layout in Ubuntu? I have found something called [KMFL](http://linux.lsdev.sil.org/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_KMFL_on_Ubuntu#Install_ibus-kmfl_package_using_Synaptic_Package_Manager.) (Keyboard Mapping for Linux), however, I could not install it because I could not find the package ibus-kmfl.

Is there maybe an easier way create a new keyboard layout? Something as easy as the [the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for that. :) That's answered my question but I can't remove the bounty of course.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

See this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) for custom keyboard layout definition

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also that article is outdated ('This article needs updating to include the latest versions of Ubuntu.') and the person who filed the [relevant bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1354968) says that it doesn't work. Could we have a detailed, working explanation of how to do this please?